# ¿Comó hacer login en PHP y Mysql con passwords encriptadas en (md5) usando AJAX? intentaba loguear con una passwd ya encriptada

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

Buen dia, intentaba loguear con un password ya encriptado, y enviando los datos del formulario de login por ajax, pero esta entrando a falso en la comparación y no loguea con password encriptado.

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function(){
      var user = $('#user').val();
      var pass = $('#pass').val();
      if($.trim(user).length > 0 && $.trim(pass).length > 0){
        $.ajax({
          url:"../Controller/loguear.php",
          method:"POST",
          data:{user:user, pass:pass},
          cache:"false",
          beforeSend:function() {
            $('#login').val("Conectando...");
          },
          success:function(data) {
            $('#login').val("Login");
            if (data=="1") {
              $(location).attr('href','index_depto.php');
            } else {
              $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>¡Error!</strong> Credenciales Incorrectas.</div>");
            }
          }
        });
      };
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<?php

session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vasco");

if(isset($_POST["user"]) && isset($_POST["pass"])) {

  $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["user"]);
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["pass"]);
  $pass = md5($pass);
  
  $sql = "SELECT User FROM users WHERE (User='$user' OR EMail='$user') AND Password='$pass'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($num_row == "1") {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //array asociativo
    $_SESSION["admin"] = $data["User"];  //variable de sesion para admin
    echo "1"; //valor que recibe ajax en caso de encontrar registro 
  } else {
    echo "error";
  }
} else {
  echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: Buen dia, intentaba loguear con un password ya encriptado, y enviando los datos del formulario de login por ajax, pero esta entrando a falso en la comparación y no loguea con password encriptado.

Comment: Deberías explicar un poco más la pregunta, explicar qué hace bien el código y donde falla, y en general dar un poco de contexto.

Comment: No uses los comentarios para dar la información sobre la pregunta, solo par aclaraciones, y de hecho si la aclaración es importante lo ideal es que edites la pregunta y añadas la nueva información.

Comment: de acuerdo. gracias

Comment: Podrias agregar el código donde muestras como guardas un usuario con su password encriptada?

Comment: ahorita lo encripto directo en mysql asi: 
UPDATE users SET Password = MD5('C3b@Dm¡N16') WHERE idUsers = 26;
Aun no hago el formulario

Comment: Las contraseñas ahorita estan como prueba encriptadas directo en mysql de esta forma: 
UPDATE users SET Password = MD5('C3b@Dm¡N16') WHERE idUsers = 26;
Desde el formulario se envia el usuario y la pass por ajax, al archivo pho de loguerar, este las recibe y la pass la lee como md5(),
Lo que sucede  es que encriptada la pass con md5 directo en mysql, no loguea, Solo en texto plano loguea.

Comment: No te aconsejo que guardes las contraseñas mediante md5(), ya que es vunerable, existe la función password_hash() y password_verify(), te dejo un enlace de la comunidad con un ejemplo: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%c3%b1as-php-y-mysql/33433#33433

Comment: si ya las he cambiado por hash, muchas gracias saludos

Answer (score 1):

Es bastante confuso lo que explicas pero si es que entendi

Tu envias una contraseña de tu formulario por ejemplo

```
usuario : test
password : 12345
```

Desde PHP, debes enviar LA MISMA password es decir 12345.

En Mysql Debes hacer esto :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Usuario
WHERE
    password = (MD5('12345'))
```

Por ende en PHP

```
"SELECT * FROM Usuario where usuario = ".$usuario." AND password = ".md5($password);
```

Esto seria lo logico, ya que cuando agregas un usuario deberia ser :

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO Usuario (usuario, password) VALUES ('$usuario', '".md5($password))."';
```

Comment: si tienes razón creo que no me explique, bien pero tienes razón en como debe ser en php. Voy a intentar Muchas gracias por la atencion, saludos

Comment: @ArmandoArellano porque lo que vi segun tu explicación es que tu envias una password YA encriptada y en tu MYSQL la vuelves a encriptar, vale decir que NUNCA seran iguales...

Comment: es cierto, me equivoque, muchas gracias

Comment: @ArmandoArellano saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, se pasa una contraseña encriptada en PHP para el inicio de sesión pero previamente la contraseña asignada al usuario fue encriptada en MySQL, entonces, el MD5 que genera MySQL es diferente al md5 que genera PHP y por ello es que no puede "iniciar sesión". Entonces yo haría algo como:

```
password_verify($clave_origen, $clave_encriptada)
```

Comment: de acuerdo, no sabia que no eran iguales los md5 generados, muchas gracias, voy a probar

Comment: posiblemente no son iguales por el mysqli_real_escape, intente verificando si el md5 de PHP es igual al md5 devuelto por MySQL. Si difieren entonces es esa función la que está generando el problema.

Comment: de acuerdo, si no probaré con hash, muchas gracias, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Ya intentaste en la linea:

```
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, md5($_POST["pass"]));
```

y elimina esta

```
$pass = md5($pass);
```