# Validar sistema de usuario y contraseña que no funciona (usando sesiones)

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente sistema sencillo de usuario y contraseña con sesiones.

INDEX:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Simplex </title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="index" method="POST" action="conectarse.php">

<h1> Bienvenido a Simplex </h1>

<h2> Ingresa tu usuario y tu contraseña </h2>

<label for id="usuario">Usuario</label>
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario">

<label for id="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
<input type="text" name="contrasena" id="contrasena">

<input type="submit" name="aceptar" id="aceptar" value="aceptar">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CONECTARSE.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'conexion.php';

global $conexion;

$usuario=$_POST['usuario'];

$contrasena=$_POST['contrasena'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";

if (!$sql) { 
echo "Verifique sus datos";   
}else{
$_SESSION['conectado']=true; //esta conectado//
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
$_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
$_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);
header ("location: menu.php");
}
?>
```

DESCONECTARSE:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset ($_SESSION['usuario']);
$_SESSION["conectadp"]==false;
session_destroy(); 
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

MENU:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['conectado']) && $_SESSION['conectado'] == true) {
echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['usuario'];
} else {
echo "Esta pagina es solo para usuarios registrados.<br>";
exit;
}
$now = time();
if($now > $_SESSION['expira']) {
session_destroy();
echo "Su sesion a terminado">
exit;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta>
<title> Simplex </title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="menu" method="POST" action="desconectarse.php">

<h1> Bienvenido a Simplex </h1>

<h2> Menu Principal </h2>

<table>

<tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>

</table>



<input type="submit" name="salir" id="salir" value="Salir">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema: cualquier comnbinacion de usaurio y contraseña que se introduzca pasa la validacion, si agrego el salto al menu de usuario este da el mensaje de que el usuario no existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El fallo esta en tu sentencia `$sql` como ya te han mencionado, el problema esta que se te ha olvidado pasar la función `mysqli_query()` para posterior comprobar si dicho registro existe en tu Base de datos.

**Dejo un ejemplo a tu estilo (Procedimientos):**

```
<?php
session_start();    

//Verificamos si no es null el formulario.
if (isset($_POST['aceptar'])) {

   require_once 'conexion.php';

   //Escapamos caracteres de nuestra cadena.
   $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['usuario']);
   $contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['contrasena']);

   $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena' LIMIT 1");

   if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)===1) {

      $_SESSION['conectado']=true; //esta conectado//
      $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
      $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
      $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);
      header ("location: menu.php");

   } else {
      echo 'Datos incorrectos.';
   }  

}
?>
```

Para crear una aplicación más segura, te aconsejo utilizar [sentencias preparadas](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php)

Aquí te dejo una [referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql) donde podrás ver un ejemplo detallado como guardar tu contraseña en la Base de datos y posterior verificarla de manera segura.

Comment: gracias, lo revisare :)

Comment: Suerte, un saludo @VictorA.

Answer (score 2):

En vez de ejecutar la query y ver su resultado, estás chequeando que un string sea verdadero (y eso siempre se cumple)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";

if (!$sql) { 
  echo "Verifique sus datos";   
} else {
  ...
}
```

Lo que debieras hacer es ejecutar ese $sql. Dependiendo de tu driver, sería algo como

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'";

$statement=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($results)===0) { 
  echo "Verifique sus datos";   
} else {
  ...
}
```

**PD**: No viene al caso para esta pregunta en particular pero siempre es bueno recalcar que hacer interpolación de variables en la sentencia misma, en vez de usar sentencias preparadas, es abrir la puerta a inyección SQL.

Con sentencias preparadas, la query se vería asi (válido para PDO)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";

$statement=$conexion->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute([$usuario,$contraseña]);
$results = $statement->fetchAll( );

if (count($results)===0) { 
  echo "Verifique sus datos";   
} else {
  ...
}
```

Como ves, con una línea extra te ahorras escapar y entrecomillar tus variables en la consulta.

**Usando mysqli la sintaxis es ligeramente distinta:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";

$statement=$conexion->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('ss',$usuario, $contrasena);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();

if ($statement->num_rows===0) { 
  echo "Verifique sus datos";   
} else {
  ...
}
```

**PD2**: Tampoco es buena idea almacenar las contraseñas en texto plano, pero dijiste que estabas haciendo un sistema simple por lo que asumo es una prueba de concepto más que un desarrollo destinado a correr en producción.

Comment: como deberia cambiar eso entonces?

Comment: habia pensado asi: $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'");
$resultado=mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if ($resultado>0) {
$_SESSION['conectado']=true; //esta conectado//
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
$_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
$_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);
header ("location: menu.php"); 
}else{
echo "Verifique sus datos";  
header ("location: index.php");  
}

Comment: Me da error:  syntax error, unexpected '$results' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Simplex\conectarse.php on line 17

Comment: ooops falta un punto y coma. Voy a editar

Comment: como estas colocando el codigo es protegido de inyeccion sql?

Comment: Si entiendo esto: execute([':usuario'=>$usuario, ':contrasena'=>$contraseña]); seria como hacer el post?

Comment: El último segmento de código, sí. Está usando un placeholder y una sentencia preparada. Ojo, estoy respondiendo con la sintaxis de PDO. La sintaxis de mysqli es ligeramente distinta

Comment: me da error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean 
placeholder es? - como podria hacerlo con MYSQLI

Comment: @VictorA. el resultado de un `prepare` fallido es FALSE, si el prepare falla, el execute que sigue intenta llamar a un método inexistente en el booleano FALSE.  Creo que es porque estás usando mysqli y yo puse la respuesta en PDO. Te dejé en la última edición la sintaxis correcta para mysqli

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all()  linea 17

Comment: Por lo visto no basta tener mysqli sino que se necesita mysqlnd. Edité por última vez mi post para usar num_rows. Si no funciona, me rindo.

Comment: ya funciono :)  gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios problemas con el código ya que permite la inyección de SQL.  Pero el problema principal está en:

```
if (!$sql) {
```

Ya que únicamente estás verificando si la variable `$sql` tiene un valor que no se interprete como el valor lógico falso (`FALSE`), cuando lo más probable es que deberías estar verificando si la ejecución del comando SQL contenido en la variable `$sql` tuvo éxito o no.

**Actualización**

En cuanto a la manera de proteger contra la inyección de SQL una manera sencilla y eficaz es utilizar comandos parametrizados.

Puedes utilizar las clases `PDO` para facilitar la ejecución de un comando SQL parametrizado:

```
$comando = $objetoPDO->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM usuarios 
     WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena=:contrasena");
$comando->bindValue(':usuario', $usuario);
$comando->bindValue(':contrasena', $contrasena);
$resultado = $comando->execute();
```

También es una buena práctica seleccionar únicamente las columnas necesarias al momento de hacer una consulta y no utilizar `SELECT *` para obtener todas las columnas.

Por otra parte, al parecer estás guardando las contraseñas sin modificar, lo cual es un gran hoyo de seguridad.  Definitivamente debes utilizar una función para obtener un hash de la contraseña, por ejemplo:

```
$hash_contrasena = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y guardar ese valor en la base de datos.

Evita utilizar los algoritmos `SHA-1` o `MD5`, ya que se han demostrado maneras de encontrar colisiones y además no están diseñados para la protección de contraseñas, sino para la comparación *rápida* de datos.  Los algoritmos para protección de datos son deliberadamente *lentos* para hacer más costoso un ataque de fuerza bruta.  La función `password_hash` de PHP utiliza el algoritmo BCrypt y puedes modificar su comportamiento con un tercer parámetro de opciones para incrementar el costo de la función (hacerla más lenta) por ejemplo.

Comment: como lo protego de inyeccion sql?

Comment: utilizo el hash cuando vaya a registrar a los usuarios

Comment: Utiliza el hash al momento de registrar a los usuarios y al momento de verificar su contraseña.