# Login con encriptacion de contraseña no encuentra los valores

Tags: php, mysqli

Posee el siguiente login con verificación de contraseña encriptada, ocurre que no encuentra el valor al comparar, que pueda estar ocurriendo?, el registro lo hago de la siguiente manera:

REGISTRO:

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$nivel   = $_POST["nivel"]; 
$unidad  = $_POST["unidad"]; 
$usuario = $_POST["txtusuario"]; 
$contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ?: '';
$pass=$contrasena;
//Encriptamos de manera segura la contraseña
$contrasena = password_hash(
                    base64_encode(
                        hash('sha256', $contrasena, true)
                    ),
                PASSWORD_DEFAULT
            );
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion,
"INSERT into usuarios (id_unidad,nivel_id,usuario,contrasena,pass) 
values ('$nivel','$unidad','$usuario','$contrasena','$pass')");
if($insertar){
    header("location: menu_usuarios_administradores.php");
}
?>
```

TABLA USUARIOS

```
id_ usuario --- usuario --- contrasena
```

Loguear

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conectar = $_POST["conectar"];

    if ($conectar == 1) {

        require_once 'conexion.php';


        $usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'];

        // Obtenemos contraseña desde un form.

        $contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ?: '';

        // Encriptamos de manera segura la contraseña

        $contrasena = password_hash(base64_encode(hash('sha256', $contrasena, true)) , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        // Sentencia SQL

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE contrasena = ?");

        // Ligamos parametros marcadores.

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $contrasena);

        // Ejecutamos sentencia.

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows === 1) {
            $stmt->bind_result($contrasenaBD);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            if (hash_equals($contrasena_hash, $contrasenaDB)) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";
                $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
                $statement->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $contrasena);
                $statement->execute();
                $statement->store_result();
                if ($statement->num_rows === 0) {
                    echo "Verifique sus datos";
                    header("location: index.php");
                }
                else {
                    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel_id from usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND contrasena='$contrasena'");
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $numfilas = $stmt->num_rows;

                    // echo $numfilas;

                    $stmt->bind_result($nivel_id);
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                        $nivel = $nivel_id;

                        // echo $nivel;

                    }

                    $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel;
                    $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; //esta conectado//
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                    $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
                    $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (5 * 60);
                    if ($nivel == 1) {
                        header("location: menu_unidades.php");
                    }
                    elseif ($nivel == 2) {
                        header("location:menu_administradores.php");
                    }
                }
            }
        }else echo "no se encontraron registros al buscar";
    }

    ?>
```

Que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero**

El resultado de hashear un string, utilizando `password_hash`, no es determinístico, porque hay un `salt` implícito en el proceso.

```
php > echo password_hash('hola',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$2y$10$sOlJwIyzEfj60JKZEyHFFOyvllOaJfAMSvERy91gL/D9Yv2J5a6xm

php > echo password_hash('hola',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$2y$10$.o3DbbpuezGWPVhlKnsKDuTJ8.LPLA2Bvlz9XDTF6GqIjrTkqorfy

php > echo password_hash('hola',PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$2y$10$a80M7S3XEg/fwoOKPcEsbu9gtgNmWiEQ1dh5ZFMn80..qUYlY9Gjq
```

De manera que **hasheando dos veces el mismo string y comparándolos, nunca se cumple la igualdad**. Lo que tienes que usar es `password_verify`.

**Segundo:**

Estás insertando la contraseña en texto plano con la variable $pass.

```
$pass=$contrasena;
$contrasena = password_hash( base64_encode ( hash('sha256', $contrasena, true)), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT into usuarios (id_unidad,nivel_id,usuario,contrasena,pass) 
            values ('$nivel','$unidad','$usuario','$contrasena','$pass')");
```

¿Estás seguro que quieres hacer eso?

**Tercero**

el algoritmo base64 es reversible, y el sha256 es determinístico. En otras palabras, añadirlos a tu función de hasheo no aporta nada.

Supongamos que primero usaste `password_hash`, sólo la primera vez, cuando insertaste el password en la base de datos

```
$pass = $contrasena;
$contrasena = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Después harías

```
$contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ?: '';

$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);
```

Y luego

```
if (password_verify($contrasena, $contrasenaDB)) {
   ...
}
```

Aprovecho de comentar que con el planteamiento anterior, no es necesario que vuelvas a consultar la fila del usuario, porque ya la hiciste antes para obtener la contraseña hasheada. Además, por la misma razón que antes, intentar hacer match re-hasheando la contraseña en texto plano:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?";
$statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $contrasena);
```

Nunca arrojará resultados, porque como ya dije, la salida de password_hash va cambiando cada vez que lo ejecutas.

Comment: lo primero: me base en la respuesta de este usuario para almacenar de forma segura las contraseñas: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql

segundo: ingrese la contraseña en texto plano para ver si las guardaba, y ya me habia percatado de que el hash cambiaba pero pense que asi funcionaba jejej

tercero: soy nuevo en esto e mysqli preparado y estaba haciendo eso que primero pasara la contraseña y luego si entrara al sistema.

Que me aportamos para cifrar las contraseñas y que esten seguras???

Answer (score 1):

Comenzando no se por que haces esto:

// Sentencia SQL

```
     $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE contrasena = ?");

 $stmt->bind_param("s", $contrasena);
```

pues segun tu tabla tienes estos campos:
id_ usuario --- usuario --- contrasena

yo modificaria:

// Sentencia SQL

```
 $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?");

 $stmt->bind_param("usuario", $usuario);
```

ya que dseo sacar la contraseña que tiene es el usuario. por que si la busco como la tienes formulada o tendras resultados con el cual comparar en caso no sean iguales.

***Como sugerencia:***

Yo te Recomendaria que te pasaras a PDO
http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php

Comment: eso lo saque de la siguiente pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql

Lo que hace esa sql es buscar que la contraseña hasheada sea igual a la contraseña que esta en base de datos y si es asi luego pasa a consultar todo el usuario y conectar

Comment: utilizo este codigo? : class MyPDO extends PDO de la web que me das?, pero seria compatible con todas las funcione stmt que tengo? --- uso para conectarme new mysqli

Comment: la cosa es que no se como llamar a la conexion para usarla en los formularios y cuando hago esto $conexion = new conexion() me dan error los prepare

Comment: creo que abra problemas, porque uso ->bind_param y son de mysqli, deberia usar esto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913601/creating-a-globally-accessible-mysqli-object