# Cómo proteger un password introducido por un formulario php, para guardarlo en un base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito guardar un *password* (que introduce un usuario mediante un formulario *php*) en una tabla de una base de datos. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
else {               
  $query = "UPDATE datos 
            SET password = '".md5(md5($_POST['password']))."' 
            WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
  mysqli_query($con, $query);                                                   
}
```

Pero no se ejecuta este `$query`, me imagino que debo tener algo mal escrito, lo saqué de un ejemplo que vi, pero no me funciona. Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos cordiales :)

Comment: podrias agrege el codigo completo  de PHP?

Comment: Este código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de concatenar valores.

Comment: Te dejo un posible respuesta a tu duda https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%c3%b1as-php-y-mysql

Comment: Muchas gracias Bulten, estoy leyendo esa respuesta y es perfecta para mi caso. Te lo agradezco mucho :)

Comment: podriamos decir que tu pregunta es un duplicado de esa?? o esta relacionada???

Comment: Está muy relacionada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando una sintaxis incorrecta para este tipo de operaciones y un tipo de cifrado vulnerable.

Te dejo por aquí [una pagina](https://alias.io/2010/01/store-passwords-safely-with-php-and-mysql/) para que le eches un ojo. Las ideas esenciales de ese enlace son:

- No almacenes las contraseñas en texto plano.
- No intentes crear tu propio sistema de seguridad de contraseña.
- No "encriptes" contraseñas (porque el proceso es reversible).
- No uses MD5.
- No uses una semilla (sal/*salt*) común para todo el sitio.
- Lo que deberías hacer:

  - Usa una función criptográfica de cifrado fuerte como `bcrypt` (mira `crypt` en PHP).
  - Usa una semilla diferente para cada contraseña.
  - Usa un algoritmo de hashing lento para hacer que los ataques de fuerza bruta prácticamente imposibles.
  - Para seguridad extra, regenera el hash cada vez que el usuario hace login.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por el enlace. La información es muy buena y ya estoy probando.

Answer (score 0):

Ah claro, habrás olvidado el punto y coma de la sentencia SQL, independientemente del punto y coma de PHP.

```
WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
```

POR

```
WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."';";
```

Explicación? Cuando ejecutas un query en la base de datos y olvidas el punto y coma al final, la consola se queda esperando a que sigas escribiendo instrucciones, es hasta que lee el ; (punto y coma) que ya ejecuta lo que escribiste y te arroja el resultado o error.