# Error Only variables should be passed by reference al Insertar datos mediante consulta parametrizada con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    public function nuevoUsuario($id_empleado, $username, $correo, $pass, $id_tipo_usuario) {
    //tiempo de espera
    sleep(1);
    try {

        $this->Conectar_BD();
        $this->query = "INSERT INTO usuarios(id_empleado, correo, pass, id_tipo_usuario, username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $this->consulta = $this->conexion_bd->prepare($this->query);
        $this->consulta->bind_param('sssis',$id_empleado,$correo, md5($pass),$id_tipo_usuario,$username);

        if ($this->consulta->execute()) {
            //Si se hace correctamente imprimimos true
            echo "true";
        } else {
            //Sino imprimimos false
            echo "false";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "false";
    }
}
```

El cual a la hora de ser ejecutado me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> **Notice**:  Only variables should be passed by reference in **C:\xampp\htdocs\SICC-GC29012018\29012018\SICC - GC\php\clases.php** on line **152**
>   false

Realmente no se a que se debe, anteriormente me funcionaba.

> **Linea 152**:

```
$this->consulta->bind_param('sssis',$id_empleado,$correo,md5($pass),$id_tipo_usuario,$username);
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que tienes exactamente en esa linea, la 152?

Comment: @iuninefrendor acabo de editar la pregunta, especifique la linea 152.

Comment: debes convertir el `md5($pass)` como una variable, intenta: `$passw=md5($pass);` y luego lo agregas como argumento.

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta PDO? En este caso estás trabajando con mysqli, no con PDO. Son dos APIs diferentes.

Comment: @A.Cedano como se diferencia una de la otra.

Comment: En tu caso concreto porque usas el método `bind_param` . En PDO sería `bindParam` y la forma de indicar el tipo de dato también cambia. Aunque en PDO puedes pasar los parámetros en un array en el ` execute`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que el error lo tienes al querer pasar ***md5($pass)*** como referencia.

Lo mejor seria guardar ese valor en una variable antes de pasarlo para *bind_param*.

Ejemplo:

```
$password = md5($pass); 

$this->consulta->bind_param('sssis',$id_empleado,$correo,$password,$id_tipo_usuario,$username);
```

**MD5**

> No se recomienda utilizar esta función para contraseñas seguras debido
>   a la naturaleza rápida de este algoritmo de «hashing».

http://php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php

Recomendado para guardar contraseñas:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

[Almacenamiento de contraseñas PHP y MYSQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql)