# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos del usuario una vez que es logueado? PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php

Este es el código que yo uso para validar que los datos ingresados en el login sean correctos , una vez que sea verificados se redireccionará a un página principal del usuario en donde yo quiero que se muestra la información del usuario que corresponde al correo y contraseña ingresados en el login.

```
        <?php
        include 'Connection.php';
        $usuario = $_POST['email']; Estos son mis campos y variables
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$usuario' AND Password='$pass'";
        $login = $conexion->query($query) ;
        var_dump($login);
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
        while($login=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          echo "<script>
                location.href='User_CUF.php';
                </script>"; (esta es la página a donde se redirecciona si el login es exitoso)
        }
```

Si alguien pudiese ayudarme se lo agradecería en verdad, debido a que el proyecto ya casi lo tengo que entregar y he estado buscando múltiples tutoriales los cuales no logro entenderles. 
De ante mano muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero cual seria tu problema?

Comment: En `User_CUF.php` pon esto: `echo ($_SESSION ['email']);`... lo mismo para los demás datos que quieras mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

que tal? no veo en tu codigo que hayas establecido una session. pero te comento, debes comenzar una sesion del lado del server, esto lo haces con session_start().
luego dentro del array $_SESSION vas almacenando los datos que queres que persistan en tu sesion.

Ej. guardas el nombre en $_SESSION["nombre_persona"] = "EL NOMBRE DE LA PERSONA"
luego en cada pagina que quieras mostrar el nombre de la persona llamas, primero siempre abris la session session_start() y luego pones: echo $_SESSION["nombre_persona"]

Espero haberme expresado bien,
saludos,

Answer (score 1):

primero debes crear una sesión como indica Sebastian para eso
primero usas el y en la pagina php donde mandes a traer los datos también necesitas una sesión:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

mandas a traer los datos que requieras del usuario:
por medio del correo por ejemplo

```
$variable = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT Nombre, Correo, password FROM myBD WHERE Correo = 'Correo'");
#guardas los datos en una var
$f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
```

ahora si!,si tu usuario y contraseña son correctas creas la sesión
con los datos que requieras y posteriormente ya solo mandas a llamar estas variables $_SESSION

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION['Nombre'] = $fila['Nombre'];
$_SESSION['Nombre'] = $fila['Correo'];
```

espero haber resuelto tu duda :D

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios huecos de seguridad y te faltan varias comprobaciones para que tu código sea sólido.

Te invito que te pases por [Evitar inyección de SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Ahora, con lo que respecta a tu pregunta, cuando ya validaste que tu usuario existe en la DB inicia una sesión en el PHP, esto lo logras con `session_start()`
Te dejo un ejemplo documentado de cómo podrías utilizarlo, quizá tenga fallos menores por que no tengo un ambiente de pruebas, pero nada que no puedas resolver muy rápido.

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
$usuario = $_POST['email'];
$pass    = $_POST['password'];

$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$usuario' AND Password='$pass'";


// Validamos si hubo un error de query o en la conexión
if( !$login = $conexion->query( $query ) ){
    echo 'Ocurrió un error en la conexión';
} else {

    // Hacemos la validación si existe el mail y el password
    if( $conexion->num_rows( $login ) <= 0 ) {
        echo 'El usuario y/o contraseña es incorrecto';
    } else {
        //No necesitas hacer un while a menos que haya más de 1 registro en el return
        $user = $conexion->fetch_assoc( $login );

        //No te olvides de siempre liberar memoria (Buenas prácticas)
        $conexion->free_result( $login );

        //Inicia tu sesión en PHP
        session_start();

        //Crea tus variables de sesión que necesites
        //La creas con el superarreglo $_SESSION y como índice el nombre que llevará
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user['Email'];

        echo "<script>location.href='User_CUF.php';</script>";
    }
}
```

Ahora no se que tengas en tu archivo `User_CUF.php`pero, la primera línea dentro del PHP debe ser `session_start()` Esto volverá a iniciar la sesión que ya habias creado en tu login, así se activará el superarreglo `$_SESSION`, en el cual ya tienes información almacenada, de hecho si haces `echo $_SESSION['mail'];` deberías ver el mail que almacenaste en el login. Sólo de esa forma puedes arrastrar datos de un lado a otro.

Te invitaría que pases por [Almacenar contraseñas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%C3%B1as-php-y-mysql) que yo hice hace varios años cuando me iniciaba en este mundo. Ahí te explican cómo debes almacenar tus contraseñas en la base de datos. Es una mala práctica que almacenes las contraseñas sin cifrarlas, un error garrafal.

Que te sirva