# Error de validación de sesiones con php

Tags: php, validación, session

Al haber creado mis datos y tener que iniciar sesión necesito que me lleve al a sesion.php pero algo falla y no sé qué lo que hace es que me lleve es al salir php adjunto acá abajo el código, requiero ayuda puesto que no logro entender bien la lógica y el funcionamiento correcto.

Abajo adjunte mi `conexion.php` mi `sesion.php` y el `loguear.php` que es el que va conectado al login para verificar los datos, como se dan cuenta el primero es `logear.php` luego adjunté la `conexión` y por último el `sesion.php` que es la página a la que se supone que debería ir.

**Este es mi código:**

*loguear.php*

```
<?php 
  include ("conexion.php");
  session_start();

  $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $password =md5($_POST['password']);


  $proceso = mysqli_query($conectar,"SELECT * FROM registro WHERE username = '$usuario' and pw = '$password' ");
  
  if($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($proceso)){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("Location: sesion.php");
  }else{
    header("Location: salir.php");
  }
?>
```

*conexion.php*

```
<?php    
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "12345";
  $dbname = "darkbins";
  //pa crear la conexion a la db y unirla a php
  $conectar = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  
  if(! $conectar){
    echo "error";    
  }    
?>
```

*sesion.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){

    echo"Session exitosa Bienvenido";        
    echo"<a href='salir.php'> cerrar sesion </a>";
    echo"Aqui se coloca toda la informacion que se requiera";

}else{
    //header("Location: index.php");
    //te manda al index para volver a colocar los datos correctamente
}    
?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es importante que `session_start();` siempre este en la linea 1 de tu codigo, y después llamas a tu conexión o el resto de código, es decir, al principio. Luego tampoco hace falta llamarlo más abajo, ya que te va generar un error. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php

Comment: gracias estás en lo cierto, no me había fijado!

Comment: De nada amig@, luego no usuario `md5` para encriptar las contraseñas, sino **password_hash()**. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Listo, pero porque esta última en lugar que md5?

Comment: Según el manual de PHP `md5` no se recomienda utilizar esta función para contraseñas seguras debido a la naturaleza rápida de este algoritmo de «hashing». Respecto a `password_hash` son mucho más seguro. Te dejo un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33420/almacenamiento-de-contrase%c3%b1as-php-y-mysql/33433#33433.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ese dato ahora sé que lo correcto es encriptar la pw usando ese método!

Comment: De nada amig@ y por cierto, bienvenido al sitio. Luego otra cosa importante, para evitar la inyección SQL en tus consultas a la Base de Datos, usaría **sentencias preparadas**, te dejo el manual como usarlo https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php y aqui información como evitarlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php

Comment: Es verdad eso tenía entendido pero como estoyempezando quise solucionar primero este error que tengo y luego pasar a proteger el sitio web contra inyecciónes sql

Answer (score 0):

Como bien menciona D.Bulten no se recomienda guardar en MD5, mira este codigo que utilizo para el proceso del Login y para hashear la contraseña.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include ('conexion.php');

    //Verificamos que este enviando desde el formulario
    if(isset($_POST)){

        $email = filter_var($_POST['txtEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $pass = filter_var($_POST['txtPass'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        //Verificamos que exista el usuario

        $proceso = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE username = '$usuario'");
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($proceso);
           
    
        //Si no existe, matamos la operación.
        if(!$resultado){
            //Credenciales incorrectas (email no existe)
            //Redireccionamos  al login
        }
        //Validamos contraseñas
        if(password_verify($pass, $resultado['contrasenia'])){    
            $_SESSION['LOGUEADO'] = true;
            $_SESSION['USUARIO'] = $resultado;            
            //Redireccionamos al perfil
            
        }else{
           //Credenciales incorrectas(contraseña incorrecta)
           //Redireccionamos al login
        } 
    }else{
        //Redireccionamos al login por que no se esta haciendo desde POST
    }
```

Y para hashear la contraseña hazlo de esta manera en tu registro.

```
$pass = filter_var($_POST['txtPass'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y asi tendras una contraseña mas segura

aqui puedes tener mas informacion
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Excelente gracias por la explicación!